# querySelectorAll is only showing odd value

Tags: javascript

I am try to **scrape** data using puppeteer. Everything is working fine but when I am running loop using querySelectorAll only odd value is storing in the data array.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let data = []; //array to hold data
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sortabletable tbody tr');

    for (let element of elements) {
      let provider = element.childNodes[1].innerText;
      let address = element.childNodes[2].innerText;//this value is not showing
      let city = element.childNodes[3].innerText;
      let zip = element.childNodes[4].innerText;//this value is not showing
      let country = element.childNodes[5].innerText;
      let phone = element.childNodes[6].innerText;//this value is not showing
      let type = element.childNodes[7].innerText;
      data.push({
        provider,
        address,
        city,
        zip,
        country,
        phone,
        type
      }); // Push an object with the data onto our array
    }
    return data; // Return our data array

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thier is always a `text or value` node inside any of tags ,  so when you fetch the `element.childrenNodes` it return the array which consist of the which store the children like eg `[text , td , text , td , text , td]` now if you will loop over the array you will find out your tags from which you want to get the innerText is at odd positions , and for the other even positions the value for innerText comes out to be undefined .

For eg . If you try to create like

```
    <p id='ps'>
      Ankit
      <a>raj</a>
      <a>rahul</a>
      amit
    </p>
```

And in now if you see using javascript :

```
const ele = document.getElementById('ps');
console.log(ele.childNodes);
```

This will also give you the same `i.e [text, a, text, a, text]` this shows that might be internally every element has the text node in between  .

Suggestion :

you should use the `children` instead of using `childNodes`
eg :

```
let provider = element.children[0].innerText;
 let address = element.children[1].innerText;
 let city = element.children[2].innerText;
 let zip = element.children[3].innerText;
 let country = element.children[4].innerText;
 let phone = element.children[5].innerText;
 let type = element.children[6].innerText;
```

Now you can start from the 0 as well .

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's because there are *text nodes* in between the elements, and the text nodes don't have the `innerText` that you're looking for:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sortabletable tbody tr');
for (let element of elements) {
  console.log(element.childNodes[1].innerText);
  console.log(element.childNodes[2].innerText);
  console.log(element.childNodes[3].innerText);
  console.log(element.childNodes[4].innerText);
}
```

```html
<table class="sortabletable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>value 0</td><td>value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Try using `.children` instead, which will iterate over *elements* (but not text nodes):

```
const provider = element.children[1].innerText;
const address = element.children[2].innerText;
const city = element.children[3].innerText;
const zip = element.children[4].innerText;
const country = element.children[5].innerText;
const phone = element.children[6].innerText;
const type = element.children[7].innerText;
```

(there isn't enough information to say for sure, but you may need to start at index 0, not index 1, if the provider is the first `<td>`)

Or, less repetitively:

```
const props = ['provider', 'address', 'city', 'zip', 'country', 'phone', 'type'];
const children = element.children;
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  props.map((prop, i) => [prop, children[i + 1].textContent])
);
data.push(obj);
```

(if the provider is the first `<td>`, change `i + 1` to `i`)

Comment: I have tried using both of your method. Thank you very much for the suggestion.